# Error using Travis CI with R package: 'roxygen2' >= 5.0.0 must be installed for this functionality

Tags: r, travis-ci, roxygen2

I am trying to use Travis CI with an R package (specifically this in-development package [here](https://github.com/jrosen48/tidyLPA)).

When I update a repository, I get the following message (see the logs [here](https://travis-ci.org/jrosen48/konfound)):

```
Error: processing vignette 'comparing-mclust-and-mplus-output.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
'roxygen2' >= 5.0.0 must be installed for this functionality.
Execution halted
```

This is consistent across two different packages--although the version of roxygen2 that I have is `6.0.1`. I haven't been able to find others with this particular issue on either Stack Overflow or the [roxygen2 GitHub page](https://github.com/yihui/roxygen2). I used `usethis::use_travis()` to set up the package for use with Travis (i.e., add [`travis.yml`](https://github.com/jrosen48/konfound/blob/master/.travis.yml) file.

Any ideas about how to address this?

Comment: An odd error, as I'm not sure what roxygen has to do with vignettes. Another occurrence: https://github.com/harrysouthworth/texmex/issues/27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I believe the problem you have is with your DESCRIPTION file.  Travis will install all package dependencies before trying to build the package / vignettes, so the version you have installed locally is of no consequence.

Rather, you need to be sure that `roxygen2` is a dependency of your package (probably only needed in `Suggests` if it is necessary to build but not use your package).  So adding:

```
Suggests: 
  roxygen2
```

To your DESCRIPTION file should fix the issue!